# How to calculate percentage from total

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

Hi Guys I am very new to tableau. I cannot seem to a find a solution for a problem I am currently facing. Following is a dashboard  I built:

[image: table view]

I am trying to calculate the clickrate of total like this:

[image: Level of detail formula]

But it gives me a very strange value.

All I need is to Divide the number of clicks of a certain ad for that week with the total no. of impressions for that week.

For example for the first ad I would do:

11/19911*100

Which should give me something like 0.055 %.

Please advise on how to achieve this. I will be very thankful.

Best

Comment: As I understand from your formula you need % of clicks for a specific AdId against whole week impression. There is a little tweak in your formula, You are using Date in LOD instead of week which might be causing this error. Just create a week function using datetrunc('week', date) and use it in LOD as well as column header. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to get the row value of clicks divided by the total impressions.

Try

```
(sum(clicks)/ sum({fixed date, ad id: sum(impressions)}))*100
```

The numerator should not have a LOD since you want each row to be divided by the total.

Comment: Thank you but this is giving me the error "cannot mix aggregate and non-aggregate attributes with this function. please advise

Comment: I edited the answer. Wrap the LOD denominator in a SUM().